# How to replace sitemap.xml in SAP Hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, sitemap.xml

Client has provided two .xml files namely a_20221229.xml and b_20221229.xml for two sites i.e, site a and site b. And they wanted to replace content of urls https://a.local:9002/sitemap.xml with a_20221229.xml and https://b.local:9002/sitemap.xml with b_20221229.xml.

I have created CatalogUnawareMedia for a_20221229.xml and associated it with site map for the given site.

Can anyone please confirm, is it correct way of doing or have to do some other way?

Replacing sitemap.xml under storefront url https://b.local:9002/sitemap.xml

Comment: Did you check SAP document? https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE/4c33bf189ab9409e84e589295c36d96e/8adb25b386691014af16eb036124f349.html?locale=en-US&q=sitemap

Comment: Hi @mkysoft, I used this link. It was helpful, but while accessing /sitemap.xml. I am getting below error Problem accessing the absolute URL "https://swc.local:9002/medias/GSBOL-20221216.xml?context=bWFzdGVyfHJvb3R8OTc2OTN8dGV4dC94bWx8aGEwL2g4My84Nzk2MTQxODQ2NTU4LnhtbHwwNGY1NWI4ZDc0ZjkyMTdlZDU0OTg4Y2FiZmNmODMyNzRlMWI4MTA4NzQ3ODAwN2JjNTk5ODMzYTdhNDBkMDUw". javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching swc.local found.

Comment: Open given url in the browser and accept security risk for testing.

Comment: Hi @mkysoft, This is not an issue with security acceptance. It is happenig due to tag <c:import var = "siteMap" url="${fn:escapeXml(loc)}"/> in which url getting passed as secure in local https://swc.local:9002/medias/GSBOL-20221216.xml?context=bWFzdGVyfHJvb3R8OTc2OTN8dGV4dC94bWx8aGEwL2g4My84Nzk2MTQxODQ2NTU4LnhtbHwwNGY1NWI4ZDc0ZjkyMTdlZDU0OTg4Y2FiZmNmODMyNzRlMWI4MTA4NzQ3ODAwN2JjNTk5ODMzYTdhNDBkMDUw. With http://9001 - which is unsecure url. Its working fine in local but failing in dev. In dev failing with both secure and unsecure url.

Comment: Then you need to use a working certificate or disable certificate check in the jvm security settings. Also you can check the existing certificate domain and configure it as test url instead of local.